# How does falling through cases in c work?

Tags: c, switch-statement

```
#include <stdio.h>

main() /* count digits, white space, others */
{
    int c, i, nwhite, nother, ndigit[10];
    nwhite = nother = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        ndigit[i] = 0;
    while ((c = getchar()) != EOF) {
        switch (c) {
        case '0': case '1': case '2': case '3': case '4':
        case '5': case '6': case '7': case '8': case '9':
            ndigit[c-'0']++;
            break;
        case ' ':
        case '\n':
        case '\t':
            nwhite++;
            break;
        default:
            nother++;
            break;
        }
    }
    printf("digits =");
    for (i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        printf(" %d", ndigit[i]);
    printf(", white space = %d, other = %d\n",
        nwhite, nother);
    return 0;
}
```

Question 1 - How does these cases work if c = 0 then does the control go to directly to the statements and break or does it remember that c = 0 and continue falling through until the statements?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int i = 0;
    for(i = 0; i < 20; i++)
    {
        switch(i)
        {
            case 0: i+=5;
            case 1: i+=2;
            case 5: i+=5;
            default: i+= 4;
            break;
        }
        printf("%d ", i);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Question 2 - In a program like this why does 2 add up in case 1? Where the current value of i will be 5? Does the control ignore all the remaining/underling case constant expressions until it finds a break if one case is true?

Comment: The first code has several mistakes and won't even compile.

Comment: "_How does these cases work if `c = 0`_" -- Did you mean "`c = '0'`"? Because `0` and `'0'` are different.

Comment: looks like homework ...

Comment: This will not even compile! What is `i « 0` supposed to do??

Comment: As a side note, you really don't need to spend effort understanding the "fall through feature" of switch-case, just know that it is there. Since "case fall though" is very bad and dangerous practice that should never be used - mainly because it is hard to tell if it was added by accident or done intentionally. (If you ever find yourself needing it, it is a clear indication of code rot or poor design.) Just add a `break` to every `case` and everything will be fine.

Comment: guys sorry about the code!

Comment: Lundin i wanted to learn what it is and how it works, not for any practical use

Comment: @Lundin, I disagree with your premise that 'fall through' is always bad.   I do agree that a lack of a comment to assure the reader of the code that the 'fall through' was on purpose is very bad

Comment: If you do use it in real code, make sure it is clearly commented as being intentional. When I've used it in the past, I've added a comment like `/* fall through */` at the point where it falls through to the next `case` or `default` label.

Comment: So how does fall through work?

Comment: for ease of understanding and readability by us humans, 1) please follow the axiom: *only one statement per line and (at most) one variable declaration per statement* 2) separate code blocks (for, if, else, while, do...while, switch, case, default) by one blank line

Comment: @user3629249 I too used to think that it was ok to use fall-through as long as you commented it explicitly. But then I started looking at the greater picture and how I ended up with the need for the fall-through in the first place. It is _always_ because of muddy thinking or poor design and there is always a more sound, more readable alternative.

Comment: @Lundin can you share a bit of your knowledge even to me by explaining how it works?

Comment: @psraganvesh If there is no break, it will fall through non-conditionally (it won't check the switch condition again) and execute the next statement underneath it. And that's that. `case` works exactly like `goto` labels.

Comment: @Lundin Thanks atlast!

Comment: @psraganvesh: there's no magic here; it's like any other sequence of statements.  The presence of the `case` labels doesn't affect execution.

Answer (score 0):

the switch in c jumps to the case with the matching value and then executes all code from there  until it finds a break or switch ends. son in 2nd example for value 0 all other cases are evaluated too. if you don't want this you need a break.